# CallDirectory Extension beginRequestWithExtensionContext not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit

I'm trying to add the CallDirectory extension to enable the call identification based on the contacts available in my app.

I have enabled the permissions under Call settings.

But beginRequestWithExtensionContext is not called even when the device receives the call.

`beginRequestWithExtensionContext` is in the subclass of `CXCallDirectoryProvider` which conforms to `CXCallDirectoryExtensionContextDelegate`

The documentation says:

> You set up both identification and blocking of incoming calls in the
>   implementation of the beginRequest(with:) method of the
>   CXCallDirectoryProvider subclass of your Call Directory extension.
>   This method is called when the system launches the app extension.

When does the system launches the app extension ?

I setup it as following in my delegate:

```
[[CXCallDirectoryManager sharedInstance] getEnabledStatusForExtensionWithIdentifier:@"com.x.CallerID" completionHandler:^(CXCallDirectoryEnabledStatus enabledStatus, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (enabledStatus == 0) {
                // NSLog(@"Code 0 tells you that there's an error. Common is that the identifierString is wrong.");
            } else if (enabledStatus == 1) {
                DDLogDebug(@"%@",@"CallerID - Code 1 is deactivated extension");
                [self enableCallerIdAlert];
            } else if (enabledStatus == 2) {
                DDLogDebug(@"%@",@"CallerID - Code 2 is an activated extension");
            }
        }];

        [[CXCallDirectoryManager sharedInstance] reloadExtensionWithIdentifier:@"com.x.CallerID" completionHandler:^(NSError *error){
            if(error) {
                NSLog(@"CallerID - refresh failed. error is %@",[error description]);
            }

            //your completetion
        }];
```

CallDirectoryHAndler.m:

```
- (void)beginRequestWithExtensionContext:(CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext *)context
{

    [super beginRequestWithExtensionContext:context];

    context.delegate = self;
     //phoneNumber , label are dummy
    [context addIdentificationEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber:phoneNumber label:label];

    [context completeRequestWithCompletionHandler:nil];
}
```

Could someone please point out What I'm  missing here?

Comment: The extension is loaded whenever it is turned on from settings or whenever you call, `reloadExtensionWithIdentifier`   If you want to debug the extension you need to attach the debugger by the process name, you can’t just “run” it from Xcode.

Comment: @Paulw11 I attached the callerID process to debugger. What would be the next step to debug ?

Comment: Well, if you attach the debugger and the debugger stops at a breakpoint in your extension then you know the extension is being loaded, which is what you are asking about. You haven’t shown your extension code, so I can’t offer any other suggestions

Comment: @Paulw11 I have only one method in the subclass of the extension and I added it to the question .

Comment: Ok. So you said that you have attached the debugger to your extension. If you set a breakpoint in that extension method and go into settings and turn your extension off/on, does it hit the breakpoint?

Comment: No, I also tried by doing a call and receiving a call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159614/discussion-between-paulw11-and-teja-nandamuri).

Comment: It's my mistake, I need to call the reload extension again in the appDidBecomeActive method. And the extension method is called now. Thanks for letting me know about the debugger info! @Paulw11

Comment: Glad you got it working. It took me quite a while to figure out how to debug the extension. Another tip is that you have very limited memory available in the extension. I used @autoreleasepool and batching to prevent my extension from being terminated during the load process.